# installed openpyxl not updated in python3 library pycharm ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, ubuntu-18.04

my OS is ubuntu 18.04, I installed python 3.8, and pip3, then installed openpyxl package using pip3 the installation was successful. But I can't find it in the pycharm library, and can't be used in my program

Comment: Please provide some more detail. Right now, we can't be sure exactly what the problem is, because we don't know any of the paths.

Comment: since i am new to all this, can you tell me what details i should provide? @TheMaker

Comment: For instance, the problem could be that the openpyxl package isn't on the right path. Or Pycharm was installed wrong. My main suggestion would be to  uninstall pycharm, and try again. But nothing can be confirmed without screenshots of the paths.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by _and can't be used in my program_?